# CPLEX12.9: Strong branching is not available for mixed-integer problems?

Tags: python, cplex

I want to get strong branching scores by cplex and python, and for the first step I just tried to use "cplex.advanced.strong_branching" to solve a very simple MILP problem (my code followed the example usage of this function exactly). However it told me that "CPLEX Error 1017: Not available for mixed-integer problems", which made me quite confused because SB should be a traditional branch-and-bound algorithm. But when I used it to solve a LP problem it worked well.

The error seemed to be raised from "CPXXstrongbranch", a base C/C++ API, which also made me question that how cplex could make SB decisions when I set the branching strategy parameter to SB. A similar question is that I know Python API doesn't have the important "CPXgetcallbacknodelp" function, so how could "cplex.advanced.strong_branching" work? Could it be the reason of this error?

I don't totally understand how "CPXstrongbranch" works in C, so the following information may be incorrect: I tried to use "CPXstrongbranch" in the user-set branch callback of the example "adlpex1.c", and the same error was raised; it stopped me to use "ctypes" to get the "CPXgetcallbacknodelp" function.

Could it be a version problem? Does Cplex block the access of SB? Because I have read a paper which relied on the SB scores in Cplex 12.6.1 and C API. Or I just made some mistakes.

My question is whether Cplex can do SB and deliver its results to users in the MILP problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cplex.advanced.strong_branching` does not carry out any branching. The doc is a bit confusing here. What this function does is computing the strong branching **scores** for the variables you pass (or all variables if you don't pass a list).

This requires an LP because usually in a MIP search tree you call this function with the current LP relaxation.

If you want to use CPLEX with strong branching then set the variable selection parameter to "strong branching":

```
with cplex.Cplex() as cpx:
    cpx.parameters.mip.strategy.variableselect.set(cpx.parameters.mip.strategy.variableselect.values.strong_branching)
    cpx.solve()
```

The `strong_branching` function is only needed if you want to implement your own branching algorithm.